# I need a small hint in my geometry task.

Tags: geometry

I was trying to solve it in different way. But as always something is missing. maybe you can see what I cannot.

> ABCD trapezoid with bases AB and CD is inscribed in a circle Ω. Point is the center of this arc CD of the circle Ω, on which there is no point A. Let ω be a circle with the center M tangent to the line AD. Point X is one of the points of intersection of the straight line CD with the circle ω. Prove that the straight tangent to circle ω at point X passes through the center of segment AB.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg1Hp.png)

Comment: You call the trapezoid $ABCD$, but your image shows $ABDC$ (points $C$ and $D$ are in the wrong order, either in the figure you made, or in the name you gave; I suspect it's the figure, but read on ...). Thus, $\overleftrightarrow{AD}$ *should* be a lateral side of the trapezoid, not a diagonal. Interestingly, however, the circle about $M$ tangent to the lateral sides of the trapezoid happens *also* to be tangent to the diagonals, so *the error doesn't matter*.

Comment: You should show (or at least summarize) the way(s) you have already tried to approach this problem. This information can help others avoid wasting time duplicating those failed attempts or telling you things you already know. Someone may also be able to quickly identify where an attempt went astray. (Also, showing your effort helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.)

Comment: I was trying in several methods. Link for graph : https://www.geogebra.org/graphing/gskpdbcj

1) Use similarities of angels MXF triangle
2) Chord of the circle CD and height MG similarities of FM length
3) And finding some equation why Length of XD matters

Comment: 4) Few equation for rectangular triangle 

And what is most important none of above are any closer to result

Comment: Also I was trying to find out why length of   $\overline XD$ matters.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the answer is quite trivial. (Correct me if my logic is wrong.)

[image]

We have a symmetric drawing with MNK as the axis of symmetry when we ignore the blue line and the green line.

We can form the circum-circle using M, X, K. By symmetry, X’ is another con-cyclic point. Then, $\angle MXK = red + blue = ... = 90^0$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

[image]

We observe that quadrilaterals $DHMI \sim AIMF$ (are similar) as the corresponding angles are equal. Thus, we get $$\frac{HM}{MI}=\frac{IM}{MF} \implies HM \cdot MF = MI^{2} \implies HM \cdot MF = r^2$$ which is equivalent of saying that point $F$ (that we know is the midpoint of segment $AB$) is at the same time intersection of lines tangent to the circle $\omega$. Which is exactly what we had to show.

P.S. when I first saw this question, my first thought was polars and La Hire's Theorem but I just couldn't find them. :/